# setting multiple jar files as classpath in cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin, classpath

I have the program `x.java` in `c:\cygwin\programs\x.java` and it uses `y.jar` and `z.jar` that are also in the folder `c:\cygwin\programs`.

In windows:

```
c:cygwin\programs>javac -classpath c:\cygwin\programs\y.jar;c:\cygwin\programs\z.jar x.java
```

No errors.

In cygwin

(1)

```
$javac -classpath c\:/cygwin/programs/y.jar;c\:/cygwin/programs/z.jar x.java 

Errors: $'PK\003\004': Command not found.
```

(2)

```
$javac -classpath c:\cygwin\programs\y.jar;c:\cygwin\programs\z.jar x.java 

Errors: -bash command Command not found.
```

(3)

```
$javac -classpath 'c:/cygwin/programs/y.jar;c:/cygwin/programs/z.jar' x.java

No error.
```

Why is it giving error in case of (1),(2)...

Comment: @AlG There is no Cygwin version of Java! java.exe is a Windows program that needs to be passed Windows-style paths.

Answer (score 2):

You are messing up with escape character back-slash `\`. In Unix based environment, it's better to use `/` as path separator. If you want to use backlashes for some reason, use an additonal backslash i.e. `\\` to treat it as literal in the path.

**Because of above, first tow statements are not resulting into correct path and hence failure.**

Comment: whats wrong with (1), i am just using `\\`  as escape char for `:`

Comment: @vjk Do you need it? If that was required then 3 wouldn't have been working, right? `c:` together represents the c drive.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin treats the `;` character as starting a new command line, so in (1) it is trying to execute the separate commands

```
$ javac -classpath c\:/cygwin/programs/y.jar
$ c\:/cygwin/programs/z.jar x.java
```

The error message is from Cygwin trying to execute the jar file directly as a script.

You can quote the entire argument with `''` as in (3), or escape the semicolon:

```
$ javac -classpath c\:/cygwin/programs/y.jar\;c\:/cygwin/programs/z.jar x.java
```

Comment: I would guess that the `:` should be used to separate paths (like in Unix land) and the first `:` should be removed (there's no need for it).

Comment: @jahroy That would be true if java.exe was a Cygwin program—but it’s a Windows program that needs to be passed Windows-style arguments whether it's being called from Windows or from Cygwin.

Comment: Got it.  Realized that after adding my comment.  I still don't think you need to specify `C:`.  You can refer to paths without it in DOS:  `cd \Users\buffoon\ ` works fine.

Comment: @jahroy But what if the working directory happens to be on drive D:\ or E:\ or X:\? Then you would absolutely need the C:\. So you should always include it.