# Java compiler does not see packages if jar on classpath

Tags: java, cygwin, classpath, javac

Why doesn't following command work?

```
$ javac -encoding UTF8 -classpath ./piccolo-1.2.jar:./piccolox-1.2.jar com/google/scrollview/ui/SVAbstractMenuItem.java
```

It produces multiple errors like

```
com\google\scrollview\ui\SVAbstractMenuItem.java:22: package com.google.scrollview.events does not exist
import com.google.scrollview.events.SVEventType;
                                   ^
```

This is real code in file SVAbstractMenuItem.java line 22, but warning statement is wrong, because package exists:

```
$ ls com/google/scrollview/events/
Makefile  Makefile.am  Makefile.in  SVEvent.java  SVEventHandler.java  SVEventType.java
```

How to teach this compiler to see packages?

**UPDATE**

Code is not mine, this is the makefile from tesseract and I am trying to run it under cygwin. Everything looks correct.

Including current directory gives the same result:

```
$ javac -encoding UTF8 -classpath ./piccolo-1.2.jar:./piccolox-1.2.jar:. com/google/scrollview/ui/SVAbstractMenuItem.java
com\google\scrollview\ui\SVAbstractMenuItem.java:22: package com.google.scrollview.events does not exist
import com.google.scrollview.events.SVEventType;
                                   ^
com\google\scrollview\ui\SVAbstractMenuItem.java:56: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SVWindow
location: class com.google.scrollview.ui.SVAbstractMenuItem
  public void performAction(SVWindow window, SVEventType eventType) {}
                            ^
com\google\scrollview\ui\SVAbstractMenuItem.java:56: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SVEventType
location: class com.google.scrollview.ui.SVAbstractMenuItem
  public void performAction(SVWindow window, SVEventType eventType) {}
                                             ^
3 errors
```

**UPDATE 2**

I found this occur if JAR present in classpath parameter.

**UPDATE 3**

I realized that if a colon would separate paths, then Windows/DOS drive letter can't handled. Hence, separating with colon is wrong.

**SOLVED**

This was Cygwin/Java incompatibility. Windows' Java uses semicolon to separate paths, while linux and makefiles expexts linux-style, i.e. colon. So it was not working under cygwin. Even replacing colon to semicolon in makefile wasn't solving the problem.

Only extracting all jars content into single plain directory helped.

Comment: Can you show your package structure and your `pwd`?

Comment: Ummm, `make` for Java? And it doesn't build?  Perhaps a build written for Java is more likely to work.

Comment: `pwd` is irrelevant, but I can say it is long; may be some truncation occurs?

Comment: @PeterLawrey it does not run as is too, not only from make

Comment: @SuzanCioc Which is why I use an IDE to make sure the paths are correct and maven to do the build and I never need to worry about these issues.

Answer (score 2):

Using javac in cygwin can be difficult. Java compiler is not a cygwin but a windows program. So you must use Windows-style paths.

Because you use the colon ":" in your classpath, your classpath cannot be correctly interpreted by the Windows Java compiler. You would have to use semicolon ";" as path seperator in your classpath. But because you are in a Unix-style shell ";" terminates your command.

Either compile your java sources without cygwin. Since the result are java class files it does not matter. Or put your parameters like classpath and also path to source files in single quotes.

Example:

```
javac -encoding UTF8 -classpath '.\piccolo-1.2.jar;.\piccolox-1.2.jar;.' 'com\google\scrollview\ui\SVAbstractMenuItem.java'
```

See also this post:
[setting multiple jar files as classpath in cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389701/setting-multiple-jar-files-as-classpath-in-cygwin)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the current directory `"."` in your classpath, so `javac` isn't even searching the correct path.

Include it in `-classpath`:

```
$ javac -encoding UTF8 -classpath ./piccolo-1.2.jar:./piccolox-1.2.jar:. com/google/scrollview/ui/SVAbstractMenuItem.java
```

Comment: I had assumed with the `$` prompt you were using straight Unix or Linux.  Because cygwin runs on Windows, perhaps a Windows path separator is needed.  Try `;` as a path separator instead of `:`.

Answer (score 0):

what i found worked after many trials was an escaped backslash at the start of the path only 
and semicolons as separators.

```
export CLASSPATH=C:\\Users/username/bla/bla.jar;C:\\Users/username/bla/bla.jar
```